# CKEditor return wrong path of image on server

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I am working on one project where I need to upload and use image in **CKEditor**. For that I have setup **KCFinder** and it works fine.(see image below)

[image: CkEditor with KCFinder plugin image]

Now when I press **browse_server** button  it shows images thumbline also and i can upload images as well.

But when i select image it returns `/images/filename.jpg`  path but that is wrong . I have uploaded image in `/upload/images/` directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found what was the problem. Set in  **KCFinder** configuration  absolute and relative path like this

'uploadURL' =>  'http://yourwebsite.com/images/',

'uploadDir' =>  '../images/',